# How to return error value and retry with timer

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java2

I'm making network requests and when there is an error like internet is offline, then it should show user an error, but retry in background so when user gets access to internet it automatically fetches data.

I have following code, which return error after retry, but I need to return error immediatelly, but don't have any clue how to do it. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

```
apiService.getForecastWeatherByLocation(latitude, longitude)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(Schedulers.io()).map { response ->
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            Resource.success(
                transformForecastResponseToForecast(response.body())
            )
        } else {
            Resource.error(response.code(), response.message())
        }
    }
    .startWith(Resource.loading(null))
    .retryWhen { errors: Flowable<Throwable> ->
        errors.zipWith(
            Flowable.range(1, 3 + 1),
            BiFunction<Throwable, Int, Int> { error: Throwable, retryCount: Int ->
                if (retryCount > 3) {
                    throw error
                } else {
                    retryCount
                }
            }
        ).flatMap { retryCount: Int ->
            Flowable.timer(
                2.toDouble().pow(retryCount.toDouble()).toLong(),
                TimeUnit.SECONDS
            )
        }
    }.onErrorReturn {
        Resource.error(AppConstants.UNKNOWN_ERROR, it.localizedMessage ?: "")
    }
```

Comment: You should consider implementing a broadcast receiver for the internet connexion error, tell me if you are interested and I will try to provide you with some code.

Comment: I know it can be done with broadcast receiver, but I want to do it the clean way with single stream.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is feasible in single stream to achieve what you want, as a stream closes once onError() is called. How about a workaround?

```
val retryObservable = apiService.getForecastWeatherByLocation(...)
    .map { ... }
    .subscribeOn(...)
    .observeOn(...)
    .retryWhen(...)

apiService.getForecastWeatherByLocation(...)
    .map { ... }
    .subscribeOn(...)
    .observeOn(...)
    .startWith(...)
    .onErrorReturn {
        retryObservable.subscribe()
        Resource.error(...)
    }
    .subscribe()
```